# Can I bind dynamic object property to v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to build a dynamic form with X number of radio options. I setup the template like this:

```
<tr v-for="question in questions"
            :class="{'table-active': question.id === currentQuestionId}"
            @click.prevent="currentQuestionId = question.id">
          <td class="cursor-pointer">{{ question.text }}</td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="y" 
                     v-model="lifetime[question.id]"
                     @click.prevent="updateAnswer(question.id, 'y', $event)"
                     name="lifetime">
              <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="n"
                     v-model="lifetime[question.id]"
                     @click.prevent="updateAnswer(question.id, 'n', $event)"
                     name="lifetime">
              <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
            </div>
          </td>
</tr>
```

Everything renders OK, but I cannot get `v-model` to bind data. I have tried initializing the object property when it mounts, Nothing happens:

```
mounted() {
  let me = this;
  this.questions.forEach(function (q) {
      me.lifetime[q.id] = '';
  });
},
methods: {
  // IF I DON'T USE THE @change EVENT, MY v-model NEVER UPDATES
  updateAnswer(id, v, e) {
      if (e.target.name === 'lifetime') {
         // @change EVENT SETS WITH VALUE BUT BROWSER DOES NOT SHOW SELECTION
        this.lifetime[id] = v; 
      }
    }
}
```

If I use a `@click` event on the radio button, it fires my `updateAnswer` method and sets the proper object property (I can see it updated in the vue-dev tools), but it is not reflected in the browser. The radio options all show as deselected. If I don't use a `@click` event at all, the `v-model` object properties never update.

My project is on Vue3, and I am still using the options API b/c the project was built on Vue2. However I tried to convert this one component to composition API to see if I could get this dynamic radio binding to object properties, but I can't get it to work there either.

What's the best way to bind these dynamic radio options so I can capture selections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `.prevent` modifier on the click events, they prevent the inputs from firing a change event. Interestingly enough, it is not just the `@click.prevent` on the radios, but also the one on the tr, as it affects the same click event when it bubbles up.

Remove the `.prevent` modifiers and it works.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: That's really odd b/c the class styling was changing on the table row, etc. Thanks for the help! I will lookup when or if I should use the `.prevent` modifier. I've got it peppered throughout my code on this project and this is the first time I've ever had an issue. I also think it has to do with the way you initialized the `lifetime` var. It was done in `setup` not on the `onMounted()` function. I get the object properties aren't reactive when done that way?

Comment: Oh, the click handler that changes the class styling is still executed, but the default action is prevented, which in this case is to cause the radio to change.  Why do you use so many `.prevent`s? I don't think I use it often, except on submits maybe. As for the `lifetime` object, in Vue 3, setting the values in `lifetime` in `onMounted()` is fine as long as the variable is declared as a reactive property, so make sure the variable is declared in `data()`.

Comment: No reason I use `.prevent`. force of habit I guess. And a misunderstanding of what it's purpose was for. But it's mostly for ajax sumbits. I have a lot of them. But in general, I couldn't get it to work until I initialized `lifetime` like you did. I do not have a `data()` function when I was using the composition api. I just declared it like `const lifetime = ref({})`  in `setup()`. Guessing that's where my issue was? Misunderstood that too. Didn't think you used `data()` with composition API.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, in composition API, you have to declare the variable in the setup block. I thought you were using Options API, because of the code in your question. Hence the `data()`, but you are right, that does not exist in Composition API.